# What is the correct term to describe the elementwise semantical relationship between two vectors?

Tags: math, topology

Say I have two vectors (or lists or any other ordered sequence), where the n-th element of the first object is related to the n-th element in the second.

Example:
I have a vector of predictions whether it will rain the next day [0.5, 0.3, 0.8] and a vector describing of whether it did rain the next day [1, 0, 1].

Now, I want to say "the elements in both vectors are ??? to each other" or "the elements in both vectors are ordered ???".

What is the term for describing this relationship/ordering/link?
(I dimly remember something along the lines of homologue, but might be wrong there.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming in the sense required hereabouts.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not directly about programming.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean (*strong*) mutual dependence - correlation

If you mean just mapping one-to-one -  bijection.